# NSNumberFormatter-DecimalStyle-When editing the formatter number, its result to 0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios4

I used below code to format the entered characters to decimal style, I use the below code in textFieldShouldEndEditing:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

long long num = [[formatter numberFromString:textField.text] longLongValue];

NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:num ]];

textField.text = formattedOutput;

[formatter release];
```

I have an issue in above code is, first time its work normally but when we going back to the textfield and edited, and coming out of it , then the value changes to 0,

For example, I entered an initial value of 123456789 and correctly got the output 123,456,789. If I then re-enter and edit the text field to 123,456,78 the field is then populated with 0,
when it should have been 12,345,678.

Comment: 123,456,78 is an uncorrect entry. Do you mean 123,456,789?

Comment: i am not entering new value , just editing the formatted number i.e., deleting the last digit, then the value is populated to 0 instead of 12,345,678

Answer (score 2):

NSNumberFormatter depends on the text going into it being properly formatted.

So when you delete the last digit from your number... that is, where the number now looks like:

`123,456,78`

The number is now not correctly formatted and NSNumberFormatter assumes it's not a valid number and returns a zero.

If you want to get foolproof long long values from your text field, remove the commas before converting (while validating the text field to make sure it's only `0-9` digits in there) and you should be good to go.